# Is there a way to capture the value by using the id of a tagName, when the id is dynamic

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to capture the value by using the id of a tagName, when the id is dynamic.
Eg: My id value currently is  id="m_7959323670053369637verificationMsg" but the "verificationMsg" remains same, only the number keeps changing. I know this question isn't clear, but I can't find a better way to put it.
What I am actually trying to do is, I am trying to capture the value that I get in the mail (the verification code), but the id is dynamic in the htmltag, and it is the closest that I can get to point out the value. 
I hope my question is understood.

Comment: What is your exact manual step which you are trying to Automate?

Comment: Since there is no code, cannot tell exactly. How about capture the value of inside the html tag to a String and using split() method with a regex?

Comment: @DebanjanB I am trying to capture the verfication code that I get in the mail, when I select the forgot password link on amazon. The tags in the mail are the same as it is an auto generated default format, but when I try thinking of an xpath to capture it or by using the tag name, the only unique tag I can see is the 'id' tag, but its value is dynamic, except that a part of it is constant. ("m_7959323670053369637verificationMsg" where "verificationMsg" is constant in all the emails). I wanted to know if there is any method that could help in identifying it like the contains() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the xpath for this type element to locate like

```
//*[contains(@id,'verificationMsg')]
```

or

```
//*[ends-with(@id,'verificationMsg')]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS identifier as well. Following will find any element which ends with

```
[id$='verificationMsg']
```

this one would also works, but it checks if string contains.

```
[id*='verificationMsg']
```

in case you need something which starts with you can use following

```
[id^='verificationMsg']
```

Comment: I still can't locate the element. Please refer to my code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816440/how-do-i-locate-an-element-whose-partialtagvalues-are-dynamic

Comment: you can't mix css and xpath identifier, css doesn't use `//` or `/` the correct css identifier would be `[id*='verificationMsg']>p:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath's ends-with method. Something like below example-

```
WebElement cls=ff.findElement(By.xpath("//*[ends-with(@id,'verificationMsg')]"));
```