# How do I locate an element whose partialTagValues are dynamic

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I get an error saying 'An invalid or illegal selector was specified'. Note:- in the last findElement statement, I have given the cssSelector as ("//td[id*='verificationMsg']/p[2]) because the id is the closest unique locator I could find to capture the data. And that part of it doesn't change. eg:- My current id value is id="m_7959323670053369637verificationMsg" where the number keeps changing in the recurring emails but "verificationMsg" part of it doesn't.

*this is in reference to my previous question and the suggestions that I got*

```js
package Amazon;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class VerifyAmazonSignInPage {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Selenium jars/chromedriver.exe");
  
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  
     driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
     driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("gaurav.thantry@gmail.com");
     Robot rob = new Robot();
     rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("******");
     rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);


     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Amazon password assistance']")).click();
String v = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[id*='verificationMsg']/p[2]")).getText();
     
     System.out.println(v);

 }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the contains method at your xpath like the following ? `//td[contains(@id,"verificationMsg")/p[2]`

Comment: You have written wrong way to locate your webelement using cssSelector locator. try this `td[id*='verificationMsg']>p[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch it guys. I got it. //*[contains(@id,'verificationMsg')]/p[2].
This works.